# Chrome --user-data-dir not working properly?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, google-chrome

So i wanted to pin different chrome instances to my taskbar. I've found this cmd line argument and I tried executing it:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"`

And It opened chrome with the default profile. I have another local profile for developing with different extensions etc. Its path is ..\Profile 1

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"`

Weird thing, it opened a somewhat guest profile, with no ability to switch to other profiles. What's wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The `User Data` folder *is* the profile.

Copy the existing `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` folder to something like `C:\Users\username\ChromeProfiles\User Data` (anywhere else on `C:\` might cause Admin access issues).

Now make a new (or copy existing) taskbar shortcut and point its Target (including quotations) to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\username\ChromeProfiles\User Data`

I use this trick to move my profile to a RAM drive on bootup (obviously w/ different path structure) and it works like a charm.

Comment: Uhh this is the right answer. Sorry unknown user: your effective suggestions go unhonored.

Comment: Also I really like the RAM drive idea. I would love to see your script and process instructions please. Is it 1) create RAM drive 2) copy user profile to RAM drive and then before shut down copy user profile from RAM drive to backup location ??

Comment: Is the --user-data-dir flag persistent (does it change the user data directory to the specified location for all Chrome instances going forward) or is it just for this instance?  In other words, if I launch Chrome with this flag, then close Chrome and use a generic shortcut to launch Chrome again without the flag, will Chrome switch back to the default user data dir?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using  `--user-data-dir` run Chrome with this parameter:

> chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1"

Comment: Do you mean to put an actual path, or just literally "Profile 1"?

Comment: Just literally "Profile 1"

Answer (score 6):

As another answer explained, your User Data folder in its entirety needs to be copied.

Hence you cannot just reference "Profile 1" **within** a User Data Folder but have to reference an **entire** User Data folder.

What you can do is
1. Copy your current User Data folder (with said guest profile) to a NEW DIRECTORY
2. Point chrome shortcut to the NEW DIRECTORY using the --user-data-dir parameter
3. After launch, notice that the profile is exactly as the original. Now modify this chrome instance, removing profiles and things you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to run this from IIS and the application pool is not set to load a profile, you'll need to set both the --profile-directory and --user-data-dir, such as:

```
chrome.exe --profile-directory="C:\temp\profile" --user-data-dir="C:\temp\profile\userdata"
```

Comment: I was upvoted, and then downvoted. Care to add a comment as to why? I use this in production servers to handle processing htm reports in the background with 10,000 end users. If there is a problem with this answer I would like to know about it.